# Getting an extension of an uploaded file in yii2

Tags: php, file-upload, yii2

I'm trying to get an extension of a file during upload but I get an error that path info requires a string:

I have tried:

```
$path_parts = pathinfo($_FILES['evidence']['name']);
echo $path_parts['extension'];
```

How can extract file extension, for example `jpeg`, `doc`, `pdf`, etc.

Comment: What does it display var_dump ($_FILES ['evidence']['name])?

Comment: am getting array (size=1)
  0 => string '254700916814.jpg' (length=16)

Comment: So you are passing an array of files. You have the name in $_FILES ['evidence']['name][0]

Answer (score 5):

If you are using yii2 kartik file input you can get the instance of [yii\web\uploadedFile](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-uploadedfile.html) this way to:

```
$file = UploadedFile::getInstanceByName('evidence'); // Get File Object byName
 // Then you can get extension by this:
$file->getExtension()
```

If you want to validate file as well then you can use [FileValidator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-filevalidator.html) using [adhoc role](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#ad-hoc-validation):

```
$validator = new FileValidator(['extensions' => ['png','jpg']]);
if( $validator->validate($file, $errors) ) {
    // Validation success now you can save file using $file->saveAs method
} else {
    // ToDO with error: print_r($errors);   
}
```

Comment: After using your example am getting an error of call of get->extension to a non  object I have also added  use yii\web\UploadedFile;

Comment: make sure that you are getting values in `$_FILE['evidence']`

Comment: after doing var_dump($_FILE['evidence']) I get  array (size=5)
  'name' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '254 713 107599 20150705_081219.jpg' (length=34)
  'type' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
  'tmp_name' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'C:\wamp\tmp\php67CF.tmp' (length=23)
  'error' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => int 0
  'size' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => int 51830

Comment: That is am getting values

Comment: This is just awesome

Answer (score 2):

It's better not use `$_FILES` directly in Yii2 since framework provides abstraction with a class [yii\web\UploadedFile](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-uploadedfile.html). There is also [separate page in guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-file-upload.html) describing working with uploaded files.

There is an example with model.

```
namespace app\models;

use yii\base\Model;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;

class UploadForm extends Model
{
    /**
     * @var UploadedFile
     */
    public $imageFile;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['imageFile'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg'],
        ];
    }

    public function upload()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            $this->imageFile->saveAs('uploads/' . $this->imageFile->baseName . '.' . $this->imageFile->extension);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, extension is extracted using [extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-uploadedfile.html#$extension-detail) property (`$this->imageFile->extension`).

There are more info about form settings, handling in controller, uploading multiple files. All this can be found by the link mentioned above.

Comment: Am usually using the ajax upload in yii2 kartik file input and the file is passed as $_FILE form

Comment: Add according details to question, because there is no mention about it in current state. But still it's better to use `UploadedFile`.